# How to run procmail in cmdline and provide .eml file as input?

Tags: linux, python, procmail

Procmail failed while running my external python script on received email. After that I tried run that script manually and provide the same arguments as procmail - it passed without any problems, so I'm trying to figure out why procmail had problems with that script. Is is possible to run procmail from cmdline and provide path to saved .eml file with email's raw data? Shall I configure something else, maybe permissions are wrong - but I guess procmail is executed by the same user as I did a manual check on python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test a script with

```
procmail -m VERBOSE=yes recipe.rc <message.eml
```

The file paths to the recipe file and/or the sample message can be absolute or relative, of course. With `VERBOSE=yes` you get verbose logging (on standard error, if you have not specified a different destination with `LOGFILE` in the recipe file); with `-m` you avoid delivering to `DEFAULT` if no recipe triggers.

If a recipe triggers and it has side effects, those will still be there, though you can often arrange your code so that delivery will happen to a separate location when a particular variable is set, so as to facilitate debugging without filling your live mail folders with test messages.

For what it's worth, `.eml` is not well standardized, though you probably mean RFC5322 (née 822) format, which is precisely what Procmail expects. There's a number of programs which use the `.eml` extension for completely different formats, though.

For further debugging tips, perhaps see also http://www.iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html